How does the charge move in an analog bucket-brigade device?
I'm trying to understand the details of a bucket-brigade delay line. The basic idea is clear: the alternating clock phases raise the voltage of alternating capacitors, causing the charge to dump into the next capacitor, causing the charges to move through the device. The part I don't understand is why the charge gets transferred entirely rather than averaged between the two capacitors.
The schematic below (source) shows the bucket-brigade circuit with PMOS transistors.   The alternating clocks cause a charge-pump action with one capacitor pulled low and the other high. Presumably, the transistor gate voltage controls how much charge is transferred and the transistor cuts off at the right point to transfer the charge and reset the capacitor, but I can't get the math to work out.

To make it concrete, suppose the clocks oscillate between 0V and -15V. Suppose the voltage at the top of C1 is -5V and C2 is 0V with both clocks off (0V). If Tr2's gate is pulled to -15V by the clock, then C2 will now be at -15V, the transistor Tr2 will conduct and C1 and C2 will average out to -10V each. When Tr2's gate goes back to 0V, C2 will be raised to +5V. So C1 is -10V and C2 is +5V which isn't what we want. But even worse, the transistor will still conduct until C2's voltage reaches the threshold, which brings us to C1 = -5V + Vt and C2 = 0V - Vt, which is about where we started. So I must be doing something wrong.
I looked at the Wikipedia page, and this answer (which has an erroneous explanation of a different circuit), and this detailed description but I can't figure it out.
